# Sending strings between c++ libraries and python

Tags: c++, python-3.x

I am attempting to pass a string from python to a c++ library.  However, I have been crashing with variations of segfaults std::bad_alloc, and invalid type messages while I have been attempting to do so.  Here is the code that I am attempting to use in c++:

```
#define DLLEXPORT extern "C"
DLLEXPORT std::string returnAString()
{
  std::string ret = "Returning string from lib";
  return ret;
}

DLLEXPORT char* returnACharArray()
{
  return "Returning char* from lib";
}

DLLEXPORT void passInAString(std::string incomingString)
{
  printf("Recieved message in passInAString\n");
  printf("Recieved incoming message: %s", incomingString);
}

DLLEXPORT void passInACharArray(char* incomingString)
{
  printf("Recieved message in passInACharArray\n");
  printf("Recieved incoming message: %s", incomingString);
}
```

Realistically, with what I am doing I can work with either the char* or the std::string once it gets in my c++ code, and I don't really have a preference either way.  Here is what I am doing in python:

```
from ctypes import *
import os
libPath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "mylib.so")
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(libPath)

string = "hello from python"
lib.passInAString(string)
#lib.passInACharArray(string)
#ret = lib.returnAString()
#print("recieved string: " + string)
#ret = lib.returnACharArray()
#print("recieved char*: " + string)
```

here, I will uncomment whichever line I am attempting to test.  When passing in a string, I will get my first printf statement, I will get std::bad_alloc.  When I pass in a char*, I get a segfault.  When I attempt to receive a message, I get back a number (I am assuming that this is the pointer), but I am unable to decode this message into an actual string message.

I have attempted to use c_char_p to convert my python string into a char* to pass to my library, but when I do that I get "invalid type".  Trying to convert the returned message by doing `c_char_p(lib.returnACharArray)` and then `print(str(string.value))` then gives me the hex value of 4 bytes... which is not what I am returning.

What am I missing to make this functionality work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DLL has the wrong argument types.
Since you're passing a string from Python the function should take a `char*`. You can convert this to a `std::string` within the function if you want to.

There's a table in the Python docs showing the corresponding types in both C and Python here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types

Edit: Just realized the string types differ for Python 3 meaning the function needs to be declared differently.
e.g.

```
// Python2, or Python3 passing bytes
DLLEXPORT void passInAString(char* incomingString)
{
    printf("Received message in passInAString\n");
    printf("Received incoming message: %s", incomingString);

    std::string myStr = incomingString;
    // and do stuff with myStr if needed
    printf("Incoming message as std::string is %s", myStr.c_str());
}

// Python3 passing strings
DLLEXPORT void passStringPy3(wchar_t* wideString)
{
    printf("Message >>%ls<<\n", wideString);
}
```

Comment: As you can see from the functions that I have available, I have the function `passInACharArray(char* incomingString)`, which I have tested with.  When I use that function though, the code prints out "Recieved message in passInACharArray", followed immediately after by a segfault.  Since you say this is the proper method of doing this, how would you write the python that calls this function?

Comment: If you're using Python3 I think you need to convert the string to a bytestring. e.g. `lib.passInACharArray(thestring.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: I've edited the code for proper strings passed from Py3.